# Functionality associating with marking buffer parts

Tags: page

Have seen the command `C-x C-p` that marks a page.  How I can use this functionality after I make a mark?

I would like to mark specific lines in a buffer, so that I can go to them later.  What can I do?  Is marks a page related to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mark-page` places the mark at the end of the page and the point at the beginning of it. The part of the buffer which is between the point and the mark is called the active region. There are thousands of commands that operate on the active region. Pick one and use it.

Comment: So it is like selected region?  I want to jump to the page mark when in the buffer.  Where can I find the list of commands that operate on the active region?

Comment: Please don't ask follow-up questions in comments.